# c# update single db field or whole object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

This might seem like an odd question, but it's been bugging me for a while now. Given that i'm not a hugely experienced programmer, and i'm the sole application/c# developer in the company, I felt the need to sanity check this with you guys.

We have created an application that handles shipping information internally within our company, this application works with a central DB at our IT office.

We've recently switch DB from mysql to mssql and during the transition we decided to forgo the webservices previously used and connect directly to the DB using Application Role, for added security we only allow access to Store Procedures and all CRUD operations are handle via these.

However we currently have stored procedures for updating every field in one of our objects, which is quite a few stored procedures, and as such quite a bit of work on the client for the DataRepository (needing separate code to call the procedure and pass the right params for each procedure).

So i'm thinking, would it be better to simply update the entire object (in this case, an object represents a table, for example shipments) given that a lot of that data would be change one field at a time after initial insert, and that we are trying to keep the network usage down, as some of the clients will run with limited internet.

Whats the standard practice for this kind of thing? or is there a method that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that updating all the columns for the entire row is a much more common practice.

If you have a proc for each field, and you change multiple fields in one update, you will have to wrap all the stored procedure calls into a single transaction to avoid the database getting into an inconsistent state.  You also have to detect which field changed (which means you need to compare the old row to the new row).

Look into using an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) like Entity Framework for these kinds of operations.  You will find that there is not general consensus on whether ORMs are a great solution for all data access needs, but it's hard to argue that they solve the problem of CRUD pretty comprehensively.

Comment: Well, as it stands right now, the update can only be for a single column, it's simply called by and event when a textbox has changed, the detection of that change is all done via the client before being sent to the stored procedure. We did it this way as the vast majority of the time, only a single field would be edited at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting directly to the DB over the internet isn't something I'd switch to in a hurry.

"we decided to forgo the webservices previously used and connect directly to the DB"

What made you decide this?

If you are intent on this model, then a single SPROC to update an entire row would be advantageous over one per column. I have a similar application which uses SPROCs in this way, however the data from the client comes in via XML, then a middleware application on our server end deals with updating the DB.

Comment: The main reason for this change was a reduction in development time, the web services were originally there as a security measure. However the switch to mssql allowed us to use application roles with stored procedures, which we felt offered enough security and a reduction in development time needed for the switchover

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is **not** to connect to DB over the internet.
Even for small app, this should be the overall model:

> Client app -> over internet -> server-side app (WCF WebService) -> LAN/localhost -> SQL
>   DB

Benefits:

- your client app would not even know that you have switched DB implementations.
- It would not know anything about DB security, etc.
- you, as a programmer, would not be thinking in terms of "rows" and "columns" on client side. Those would be objects and fields.
- you would be able to use different protocols: send only single field updates between client app and server app, but update entire rows between server app and DB.

Now, given your situation, updating entire row (the entire object) is definitely more of a standard practice than updating a single column.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to only update what you change if you know what you change (if using an ORM like entity Framework for example), but if you're going down the stored proc route then yes definately update everything in a row at once that's way granular enough.

You should take the switch as an oportunity to change over to LINQ to entities however if you're already in a big change and ditch stored procedures in the process whenever possible

Comment: Baring mind this is a relatively small application, entity framework seemed like overkill. Also you say "ditch stored procedures in the process whenever possible" why is that?

Comment: Entity Framework isn't overkill, new techs are simpler not more complex than old ones. The reason i suggest ditching storing procédures is because it's less of a pain to maintain, even more so in your case if you're alone, everything is in code in LINQ, no deployments to sync with your DBA, no sql statements outside of your source control etc. Since i transitioned to entity frame / linq mindset (back in the very early days of linq to sql), i haven't had to type more than a couple dozen lines of sql, and i don't miss it.

Comment: I have guy who does the DB work, as i'm far from being a TSQL expert, he handles the stored procedures. We used them after several suggestions on previous questions about it adding additional security, since these clients access the DB across the internet (via ssl)

Comment: That's the whole point, entity Framework removes the need for the guy who does the db work, doesn't require you to know any TSQL, and will make you a better C# programmer to boot as linq to entities & linq to object have similarities and will go nicely together if you learn both. I don't think it's a good idea to expose your DB directly on the net however, i definately'd go back on your decision (keep web services, ditch stored procédures instead of the oposite that you picked)